# How can I find Thevenin Equivalent Voltage in the given circuit?

Tags: thevenin

How can I find Thevenin Equivalent Voltage across a & b in the following circuit?

[image: The given circuit]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework question with no demonstrated attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The easiest method for this case is to use superposition. Turn off all independent sources except one and calculate the voltage across a and b. Repeat until you've found the contribution for all sources. Add the contributions from each individual source to get the Thevenin equivalent voltage for all of them.

Remember that turning off a voltage source means replacing it with a short circuit, and turning off a current source means replacing it with an open circuit.

Comment: This is the kind of answer all homework questions show get. Well done! +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have one more question. When I turn off all the independent sources except the 20V one, what will be the Voltage across a & b? 20V or -20V and Why?

Comment: @user3417785 The problem is looking for the voltage from a to b so the voltage is positive if the voltage at a is higher than the voltage at b. The 20V source's negative terminal looks to be connected to the a side so a is at a higher voltage than b. So the voltage is -20V.